# Why do I get a "can't edit this property from a linked data block" message when trying to edit an appended object?

Tags: append

I'm trying to append a model from one file to the other but every time I try it's acting like it's linked but I cant even move it or scale it.

If I try to I get the message "can't edit this property from a linked data block"

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, found it. Had to go to out-liner and delete the linked data from there, works like a charm now.

Comment: Can you explain this further? Having the same issue and I'm not sure what exactly you mean.

Comment: Deleting the offending collection and going to *File > Clean Up > Purge All* will remove the linked data blocks, you can then re append the collection. This happens every time that you link a collection prior to appending it.